# DW5.5 JQM/Phonegap - Cannot emulate app

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, dreamweaver

I cannot get DW 5.5 to emulate either the Meriden example app or one that I've written (working through an example in a book). I'm on XP SP3.

The build goes just fine, the emulator launches, but in one of the java windows that pops up I see "error loading preferences".  In the emulator, my app does not appear and DW reports a problem with starting the emulator.

Any ideas?  How can I check my installation of the SKD (and I guess JRE)?

Also, can I launch the build app in the emulator myself - is there a command line I can use?

Many thanks

Abo

Answer (score 0):

I know that Dreamweaver CS5.5 has an update that specifically covers a problem with the Android emulator: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/904/cpsid_90408.html   Not sure that it will specifically help with this issue, but try that first.